# Qt QGraphicsView: Displaying QGraphicsView inside a tab

Tags: c++, qt

I will describe my issue.

I have a class for tab, which looks approximately like this:

```
class Tab : public QWidget
{
public:
  Tab();
   ...
private:
   ...
  QGraphicsView *view;
   ...
};
```

In `Tab()` I create the `view`. Now in my main window I would like to have a `QTabWidget`, which contains some tabs, where each tab displays a `QGraphicsView`. It looks approximately like this:

```
class MainWindow : QMainWindow
{
public:
  MainWindow();
   ...
private:
   ...
  QTabWidget *tabWidget;
   ...
};
```

and

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
  tabWidget = new QTabWidget(this);
  tabWidget->addTab(new Tab, tr("tab 1"));
  tabWidget->addTab(new Tab, tr("tab 2"));

  setCentralWidget(tabWidget);
}
```

This doesn't display the `QGraphicsView`s in the tabs. To make the `QGraphicsView`s visible, I would have to write something like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
  tabWidget = new QTabWidget(this);
  tab1 = new Tab;
  tab2 = new Tab;
  tabWidget->addTab(tab1->view, tr("tab 1"));
  tabWidget->addTab(tab2->view, tr("tab 2"));

  setCentralWidget(tabWidget);
}
```

and `view` would have to be public in the class `Tab`, which really looks bad. The class `Tab` has some private functions, which are used to construct `view` and I don't want `view` to be public in `Tab`.

How to get around this?

I was thinking of creating a class, which inherits from `QGraphicsView` and adding my own functions, but I'm not quite sure how to do this so that it works for me.

Thank you for your answers and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely because `Tab` doesn't have a layout (or you even have not added `view` as a child of `Tab` widget). You didn't show `Tab` constructor, so I can't know for sure.

If a tab can contain only a view, then you need to derive `Tab` class from `QGraphicsView` instead of `QWidget`. Additional `view` class member should be removed, and you can use `Tab` objects as if it would be `QGraphicsView` objects.

If a tab can contain other widgets, then you should add a layout to your `Tab` object and add the view and other children to this layout. Example:

```
Tab::Tab() {
  QVBoxLayout* main_layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
  view = new QGraphicsView();
  main_layout->addWidget(view);
}
```

Comment: Yes! The thing with layout works. I just don't get how this works. Can you give me a link to some text where I can read about this? Thank you.